# Project can't be open in visual studio

Tags: c#

I have created a project but when I creating the form I forgot to write code to exit button and form size equal to the screen.

Then I run the project and it couldn't close it. So I was shut down the machine using the power button and it open again. But when I try to open the project it was not open shows following error. I did it before but this error didn't come before.

I have no idea how to fix this. I looked at the folder it has the project.

**Error**

> C:\Users\kularathna\source\repos\Defect Management System\Defect
>   Management System\Defect Management System.csproj : error  : The
>   project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing. 
>   C:\Users\kularathna\source\repos\Defect Management System\Defect
>   Management System\Defect Management System.csproj

[It shows like this how can I open my project again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdLRa.png)

[This is my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLXWb.png)

[My DefectManagementSystem.csproj look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN3Hk.png)

Comment: Broken file. Restore it from version control and redo possible changes. And never force computer to turn off. You can log off, alt-tab, kill process from task manager etc instead.

Comment: Can I open the project again??

Comment: If you restore the file from version control, probably. Or you can open it in a text editor and see if it’s manually repairable

Comment: I don't know to do it. Can you help me

Comment: If you have the project under version control (e.g. git), just rollback some commits. However if you don't, you have to either manually fix it somehow (show us the .csproj file, maybe we can help), or manually rebuild the project by doing some copy pasting.

Comment: I open the csproj file it shows numbers I will show it to you update my question.. no, I'm not using git.

Comment: Now I update the question. my csproj file only shows numbers. but I looked at another project it contains xml codes.

Comment: how can I open my project again